# HMR Not Reloading When Typescript Files Change - VS 2017 / Webpack

Tags: typescript, reload, hot-module-replacement

Any HTML changes fire the HMR reload just fine. But for some reason typescript files no longer do. They were working in VS 2015, but stopped working when I moved to VS 2017 yesterday.

Using VS 2017 with Webpack in an Angular 2 app.

Like I say, HTML files still work fine, just TS files are the problem. I don't know that much about the mechanism for triggering the reload and googling isn't getting me anywhere. I would appreciate any help anyone can give me.

Thanks!

Buzz

Answer (score 0):

Firgured this out, it's a simple fix:

In the tsconfig.json file, in the "compilerOptions" section, add this entry:

**"compileOnSave": true**

That's it. Hope this helps someone.

Thanks,
Buzz